# Knockout textbox bound to numeric field

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mapping-plugin

I've implemented a form using KnockOutJs but I realize that the textboxes that bind to numeric fields have a default value of '0' (Zero). Is there a way of making the textbox empty by default rather than defaulting to '0' (Zero)?

Comment: Defaulting to '0' is a sensible implementation, it shows your users that it is supposed to be filled with a numerical value. So why do you want to have it empty instead?

Comment: The users have asked for it to be empty. They do not want to have to delete the '0' before they input their data.

Comment: @ThaMe90 that is completly wrong! 0 and null is not the same thing

Comment: @Anders Who said anything about null?

Comment: Empty (null, "" etc) and zero are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set default textbox value to empty string when define the observable property:

```
self.myObservableField = ko.observable("");
```

Comment: Thanks! I was actually using the mapping plug in and formatting the input but this led me in the right direction. I ended up doing something like this: <code>            if (valueToWrite == 0) { //We want the default to be 0.
                valueToWrite = '';
            }</code>